# Re - Sub all numbers except $ and percentages

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression in Python to sub numbers that **aren't** dollar values or percentages with x's. Here is an example sentence:

```
s = "Hi there my name is Jon Doe, I haven't been here for 4 years, my birthday is 1/23/92, I received 10% off of my $20.50 purchase."

re.sub(<pattern>, 'x', s)
```

I would like the output to be:

```
Hi there my name is Jon Doe, I haven't been here for x years, my birthday is x/xx/xx, I received 10% off of my $20.50 purchase.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use [negative lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: This is going to be complicated until you figure out how you want to define "number" in a way that treats `20.50` as a single number (so you skip all of `$20.50` instead of just the `$20` part). So first, write a regex for "number". Then the negative lookbehind and lookahead are still a problem, because you want to make sure that, e.g., the `%` in `10%` means you skip the whole `10`, not just greedily match the `1` then skip the `0%`. This is a hard problem, so it's likely you'll get stuck somewhere, but ask once you've gotten stuck, instead of asking for a regex you probably won't understand.

Comment: My apologies, I should've posted my attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least this might be an attempt to discuss about, as @abarnert said.

```
re.sub('(?<![$.0-9])\d*[.]*\d+(?![%.0-9])', 'x', s)
```

It's about searching for bunches of numbers which can have periods in the middle or the beginning (`\d*[.]*\d+`) surrounded by negative lookarounds with regards to digits, periods and dollars before / percentages after (`(?<![$.0-9])`and `(?![%.0-9])`).

Output:

```
"Hi there my name is Jon Doe, I haven't been here for x years, my birthday is x/x/x, I received 10% off of my $20.50 purchase."
```